# Joining 2 tables (a, b) and returning values that are NULL in (b)

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to join 2 tables (a, b) and returning values that are NULL in (b). I'm working with 2 tables -- called `cookies` and `all_desserts`. Cookies exist in `all_desserts`, but I want to get a table that displays values of `all_desserts.names` - `cookies.names`.

Essentially, I want to show all the desserts in the desserts table that are NOT cookies. I think I need to use null here and a right join. I would like to call this new table `desserts_without_cookies`.

Here is what I have so far (which doesn't work). Am I doing the wrong type of join?

````
FROM cookies LEFT JOIN desserts.cookies ON cookies.cookie_name = desserts.cookies
WHERE desserts.cookies IS NULL```
````

Comment: Could you provide structure of the tables: tables' names and columns ?

Comment: Basically what you are asking is impossible without more information about the table. Which column is null in cookies, are the tables constrained in foreign primary key manner? Would you even have a all_desserts row with cookie set to null? If so why not just get that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select ad.*
from all_deserts ad
where not exists (select 1 from cookies c where c.names = ad.names)
```

A `LEFT JOIN` would also work:

```
select ad.*
from all_deserts ad left join cookies c 
on c.names = ad.names
where c.names is null
```

Comment: Could you clarify what "ad." is? So in this example, the columns im changing are: ```cookies.cookie_name``` and ```all_desserts.names``` @forpas

Comment: @springy11 It is a table alias defined after table name. When joining tables it is usually good practice to alias those so you can refer to the corresponding table in the join.

Comment: `ad` and `c` are the aliases of the table names. So `ad.*` means all the columns of the table `all_deserts`

Comment: I'm still a bit confused -- wouldn't this change given the column names? In the post, I mentioned that the columns I want to join are all_desserts.names -cookies.names  (they both have the same column name even tho they are 2 different tables)

Comment: thank you for editing! i understand the alias now. I'm getting an aerror that says: "=" cannot be applies to varchar

Comment: '='cannot be applied to varchar, bigint @forpas

Comment: Which columns are varchar and bigint. And are you sure that you are using MySql?